# Hive: External table output result is NULL

Tags: hive

I created external hive table like this.

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE parquet_emp_parquet(id string, name string, city string) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 'wasb://sparkblob@lntsparkblobaccount.blob.core.windows.net/empparquet';

but i got output,

```html
+-------+-------+-------+--+
|  id   | name  | city  |
+-------+-------+-------+--+
| NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
| NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
| NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
+-------+-------+-------+--+
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive is very sensitive to column name.

In my case i have created parquet file using spark2.0.2 dataframe. while creating hive table there is mismatching in names as i had given to spark dataframe.

It's resolved, I have given same schema while creating external hive table as i had given to create parquet file.